# Horowitz' improvised run during performances of fantaisie-impromptu

Tags: ear-training, transcription, chopin

I'm hoping this is the best place to ask how to play the decorated run that Horowitz improvises towards the end of the second section in his performance of Chopin's fantaisie impromptu? I can't find any transcriptions of it on the Internet but if anyone can transcribe by ear or has a script already, I would be very grateful! Below is an image of the standard notation as well as a link to Horowitz' interpretation (the phrase in question is played at 2.35 on the video)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This looks like it:

[image]

Note that the bass notes for the last beat are copied from the first two editions I looked at (Paderewski and Fontana); the treble notes are also written as straight quavers, though no doubt many people play them dotted.

Comment: "though no doubt many people play them dotted." Why? If Chopin had wanted to write this section in 12/8 time, he would have done that. The whole piece is built on cross-rhythms, for example 4 against 3 in the fast sections. The first edition gives two 8th-notes on the last beat, though some later editors (who obviously knew how to compose better that Chopin!!!) - not to mention some performers - are notorious for messing around with the score to suit their own whims and fancies. Also Chopin wrote the third beat as Horowitz played it, but grace notes- only the first two beats are by Horowitz.